# using methods from user library in multiple packages(Java,Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I create a new user library named reference and I add a JAR file called stdlib to this library. Then I creat two classes. Class A with main method is in the default package. Class B is in other package. 
 It's OK to use methods in reference library in Class A. For example, StdOut.println(); 
However, the program cannot recognize it when I use it in Class B, which is in another package.

Then I built a new class C in the default package. the reference library works fine in Class C.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my program? Why can't I use methods from reference library in Class B, which is not in the default package? Thx!

Comment: have you added the user libraries to your build path?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're just missing an import:

```
import foo.bar.ClassB;
```

where `foo.bar` is the package containing `ClassB`.

(As an aside, I'd strongly advise against using the default package in your own code.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I didn't miss to import Class B in Class A. Even if I missed, I think Eclipse should recognize the methods from the user library. The thing is that I cannot put methods from user library to use in packages except the default package.

Comment: @user2256289: Sorry, I'm finding it hard to understand exactly what you mean. If you haven't got an import, then any Java compiler *will* fail to find the classes which aren't in those packages. (Note that classes are in packages, not methods.) If you could post a short but *complete* example of the problem in your question, it would make it a lot easier to follow.